# Funcion encontrar penultimo valor de un arreglo y encontrar primer valor impar

Tags: javascript

Bueno estaba realizando este ejercicio en JS --->

"Crea una función para un array de números.
La función debería imprimir el penúltimo valor y el primer valor impar del arreglo."

```js
function Devuelve(x) {
  var primer_imp = 0;
  var penultimo = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    // BUSCAMOS PENULTIMO VALOR
    if (i == x.length - 2) {
      // ENCONTRAMOS PENULTIMO VALOR DEL ARREGLO
      penultimo = x[i];
    } else {
      // NO ES EL PENULTIMO VALOR
    }
  }
  /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
  for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    if (x[j] % 2 == 0) {
      // ES NUMERO PAR
    } else {
      // ES IMPAR
      primer_imp = x[j];
    }
  }
  console.log("");
  return (
    "Penultimo valor es: " +
    penultimo +
    " y el Primer valor impar es: " +
    primer_imp
  );
}
y = Devuelve([6, 30, 10, 1, 5, 4]);
console.log(y);
```

** FUNCIONA ENTREGAR EL PENULTO VALOR PERO NO ENTREGA EL PRIMER IMPAR DEL ARREGLO** // Alguien me puede decir como puedo arreglar esto? y resolver el ejercicio? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego código con explicación en comentarios:

```js
function Devuelve(x) {
  var primer_imp = 0;
  var penultimo = 0;
  
  // 1. El penúltimo valor se encuentra directamente
  if(x.length > 2)
    penultimo = x[x.length - 2];

 
  
  for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
  // 2. Simplificar la condición
    if (x[j] % 2 != 0) {
      primer_imp = x[j];
      // 3. cuando se encuentra el primer impar se termina el ciclo
      break
    } 
  }
  console.log("");
  return (
    "Penultimo valor es: " +
    penultimo +
    " y el Primer valor impar es: " +
    primer_imp
  );
}
y = Devuelve([6, 30, 10, 1, 5, 4]);
console.log(y);
```